# Order data based on count of related table data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have Two diff tables as given below:

users and posts

Need data from user's table order by count of posts table

Relationship is defined as:

```
User Model:

public $hasMany = array('Post');

Post Model

Public $belongsTo = array('User');
```

Comment: Do you nee da solution in SQL?

Comment: I would prefer in cakephp format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510621/need-a-sql-query-to-find-posts-with-most-commented-order-by-comments-number-coun

Comment: @ArunJain : I have seen this question but is there any solution in cakephp format data retrival..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**counterCache - Cache your count()**

This function helps you cache the count of related data. Instead of counting the records manually via **find('count')**, the model itself tracks any addition/deleting towards the associated **$hasMany** model and increases/decreases a dedicated integer field within the parent model table.

The name of the field consists of the singular model name followed by a underscore and the word “count”:

```
my_model_count
```

Let’s say you have a model called **ImageComment** and a model called **Image**, you would add a new INT-field to the **image** table and name it **image_comment_count**.

Once you have added the counter field you are good to go. Activate counter-cache in your association by adding a **counterCache** key and set the value to **true**:

```
<?php
class Image extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ImageAlbum' => array('counterCache' => true)
    );
}
```

From now on, every time you add or remove a **Image** associated to **ImageAlbum**, the number within **image_count** is adjusted automatically.

You can also specify **counterScope**. It allows you to specify a simple condition which tells the model when to update (or when not to, depending on how you look at it) the counter value.

Using our Image model example, we can specify it like so:

```
<?php
class Image extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ImageAlbum' => array(
            'counterCache' => true,
            'counterScope' => array('Image.active' => 1) // only count if "Image" is active = 1
    ));
}
```

Comment: See this url http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count