# cakephp / php Mysql complex query for dashboard statistics

Tags: php, statistics, dashboard

I have following mysql database tables:

`cities`

`states`

`countries`

with

`members`

`samajs` (a group of people internationally)

and I want to create a query for my `dashboard` page which will have following results:

```
Country   Members Samajs Total   (table header)

Country1    7      5     16      (country row with total members, samajs and total count)

  state1    5      2     7       (state row with total members, samajs and total count)

    city1   3      1     4       (all cities in that state, city row with total members, samajs and total count)

    city2   2      0     2         

  state2    2      1     3

Country2    3      2     5      (country row with total members, samajs and total count)

 ...and vice versa....
```

Here, `members` table will have `country_id, state_id and city_id` as foreign key

`samajs` table will also have  `country_id, state_id and city_id` as foreign key

Any idea, what will be query for same?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a query change is according your table fields:

```
// for country based 
SELECT  
countries.name AS countryName,
(SELECT
count('x') FROM members WHERE members.country_id = countries.id) as totalMembers,
COUNT(samajs.country_id) as totalSamajs
FROM 
    `countries`
INNER JOIN samajs ON samajs.country_id = countries.id
GROUP BY 
    countries.name
ORDER BY
   totalMembers DESC

// state based result

    SELECT  
states.name AS stateName,
(SELECT
count('x') FROM members WHERE members.state_id = states.id) as totalMembers,
COUNT(samajs.state_id) as totalSamajs
FROM 
    `states`
INNER JOIN samajs ON samajs.state_id = states.id
GROUP BY 
    states.name
ORDER BY
   totalMembers DESC

//city based result

SELECT  
cities.name AS cityName,
(SELECT
count('x') FROM members WHERE members.city_id = cities.id) as totalMembers,
COUNT(samajs.city_id) as totalSamajs
FROM 
    `cities`
INNER JOIN samajs ON samajs.city_id = cities.id
GROUP BY 
    cities.name
ORDER BY
   totalMembers DESC
```

and as per cakephp method you can follow this question:
    [Order data based on count of related table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297743/order-data-based-on-count-of-related-table-data/12298086)

Comment: thanks for the quick response, it works fine for country however how can i modify it for state/city combination? please let me know..

Comment: tnx but can't i manage all things from single query, as in cakephp it will be little difficult to manage diff queries for all

Comment: then you shoud follow the link given and add countercache in relatioship

Answer (score 1):

Finally, made a single query, which brings me the result as expected with help of `union` and `subqueries` as below :

```
SELECT country_id, state_id, city_id, country, membercount, samajcount FROM
        (

        SELECT con.country_id, -1 as state_id, -2 as city_id, con.country, 
        (SELECT COUNT(member_id) FROM members WHERE country_id = con.country_id) as membercount, 
        (SELECT COUNT(samaj_id) FROM samajs WHERE country_id = con.country_id) as samajcount
        FROM countries as con
        group by con.country  

        UNION 

        SELECT s.country_id, s.state_id, -2 as city_id, s.state as country, 
        (SELECT COUNT(member_id) FROM members WHERE state_id = s.state_id) as membercount, 
        (SELECT COUNT(samaj_id) FROM samajs WHERE state_id = s.state_id) as samajcount
        FROM states as s
        group by s.state  

        UNION

        SELECT c.country_id, c.state_id, c.city_id, c.city as country, 
        (SELECT COUNT(member_id) FROM members WHERE city_id = c.city_id) as membercount, 
        (SELECT COUNT(samaj_id) FROM samajs WHERE city_id = c.city_id) as samajcount
        FROM cities as c
        group by c.city  

        ) COUNTRY  

        order by country_id, state_id, city_id, country ;
```

Hope it helps someone for their requirements !!

Thanks